# how to make url shorter in web2py and google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, url, routes, web2py, domain-name

I've been trying to make URLs shorter. For example, change

```
www.mydomainname.com/myapp/default/mypage
```

to `www.mydomainname.com/mypage`

I add the following code in routes.py under the web2py folder:

```
routes_out=(
    ('.*:/sevenpeng/default(?P<any>.*)', '\g<any>'),)
```

But this didn't work. The url still shows `www.mydomain.com/default/mypage`
Am i missing something?

Another problem, I deployed my website on google appengine, when I typed www.mydomainname.com, it directs to the right page, and the address is still www.mydomainname.com. However, when i typed directly mydomainname.com into browser, the address changes to 1.myapp.appspot.com/myapp. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to remove the app name and the "default" controller from the URL is to use the [parameter-based rewrite system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/4#Parameter-based-system), as follows:

```
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application = 'myapp',
        default_controller = 'default',
        default_function = 'index',
    ),
)
```

The above goes in /web2py/routes.py. Note, the parameter-based system cannot be mixed with the [pattern-based system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/4#Pattern-based-system).

Comment: Thanks. But I have several controllers, and I don't want the controllers's name to be showed.

Comment: Maybe something like `routes_in = (('/(?P<any>func1|func2|etc)', '/myapp/controller1/\g<any>'), ('/(?P<any>func3|func4|etc)', '/myapp/controller2/\g<any>'))`

Comment: routes_out will generate the shortened URLs via the `URL()` function, but when someone follows a link generated by routes_out, you'll need a corresponding routes_in to properly convert the incoming request to the correct web2py route.