# Hide all controller and function names from the URLs web2py

Tags: python, url, model-view-controller, web2py

[Similar question, which didn't solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671936/how-to-make-url-shorter-in-web2py-and-google-appengine).

I want my app to have unique string identifiers (slugs) for every page, and to make URLs shorter I'm trying to hide the controller and function names from the URL. So, instead of this:

```
mysite.com/app/c/f/my-slug
```

I'd like to get this:

```
mysite.com/my-slug
```

The best I can get (using URL rewriting) is this:

```
mysite.com/f/my-slug
```

If I just set "c" as default controller and "f" as default function and try to visit app/some-slug (given that "f" can handle such slug), web2py gives an "invalid controller (my)" error.

Since I couldn't get the pattern-based URL rewriting to work (maybe because I just did it wrong), I think I would need to store each slug along with its default controller and function names in the DB and some kind of "universally default" function to handle all this. Then, if I needed to do another action to some page, I'd put the action name in front of the slug in the URL.

So... Is it feasible? Exaggerated? A terrible idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In routes.py, you can do:

```
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application='myapp',
        default_controller='default',
        default_function='index',
        functions=['function1', 'function2', 'function3']))
```

In that case, /my-slug will be routed to /myapp/default/index/my-slug.

If instead you want to map different slugs to different controllers and functions, you could do that by looking up the slug in a database (or some other means of storage) and setting `request.controller` and `request.function` in a model file, but you probably don't want to have to do an extra database lookup on every request. Instead, you could use the pattern-based re-write system, but you'll have to set up patterns for every slug.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I beat my head against the wall for some time until I remembered that the right key is "routers" instead of "router" (maybe you'll want to change that in your answer) and that I should place myapp's default controller and function in a "myapp" key if want to use more than one application (such as admin) with different controller and/or function names.

Comment: However, I have one more question: The slugs will be unpredictable, so I can't use the pattern-based system (unless I write some code to add and remove them dynamically and reload routes.py). I'm pretty sure that almost every page will be loaded from the DB anyway, so will the impact of the lookup be still so negative? Could I, for example, do the lookup and then send the contents of the DB entry as a parameter to the function so to avoid unnecessary double queries?

Comment: If the content for each slug is in the DB, then just use the above routing, and let the index function retrieve the content associated with the slug. Within the index function, you will be able to access the slug via `request.args(0)`. So, the index function might just be `return dict(content=db.content(slug=request.args(0))`.

Comment: I used this example with good result but noted that it only worked for my index page. I have multiple controllers and would like to have them (the controller names and the functions) to be hidden. Is there a better way?

Comment: Using the parameter-based routing system (as shown above), you can hide only one controller per app and one function per controller. Logically that makes sense, as you need some way for incoming URLs to be routed to the appropriate controller (if a given URL has no controller and you have two "hidden" controllers, how would the routing system know which one to route to?). If you need something more complex, you'll have to switch to the pattern-based routing system (even then, the URL will have to contain *some* information to indicate the appropriate controller and function).